# MongoDb BsonClassMap

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database

I'm new to MongoDb and I'm currently using the CSharp drivers (version 1.2). My problems occur when using BsonClass map. Below is the code I'm tring to execute. I've simply defined a custom type I'd like to map to a BsonDocument.

In order to use this I'm taking advantage of BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(). When I hit the foreach statement (trying to access the first entry in the FinAs() results) I get the following error:

'Cannot deserialize Guid from BsonType ObjectId.'

From what I understand BsonClassMap uses GuidGenerator for objects of type Guid. Why am I getting this error?

Please note that the insertion is performed without any errors...and after performing the insert, newEmployee has an EmployeeId that's been automatically generated for it.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
     class Program{

        static void Main(string[] args){

            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create();

            MongoDatabase dataBase = server.GetDatabase("test");

            MongoCollection<Employee>employees = dataBase.GetCollection<Employee>("employees");



            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Employee>(cm =>
                                                    {
                                                        cm.MapProperty(c => c.Name);
                                                        cm.MapProperty(c => c.Email);
                                                        cm.MapIdProperty(c => c.EmployeeId);
                                                    });

            var newEmployee = new Employee{ Name="Test", Email="test@test.com"}; 

            employees.Insert(newEmployee);

            foreach(Employee e in employees.FindAs<Employee>(Query.EQ("Name","Test")){

                Console.Writeline(e.Name);

            }

        }
     }

     public class Employee
     {
         public Guid EmployeeId {get;set;}
         public string Name {get;set;}
         public string Email {get;set;}
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some additional documents stored in my collection before I started using BsonClassMap. Their ObjectId was stored in a format native to MongoDB....unfortunately this format couldn't be parsed to a Guid. To fix the error I ended up wiping out all old entries.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to use [SetIdMember](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-IdentifyingtheIdfieldorproperty) to identify your id field.  Any particular reason you aren't using `ObjectId` values instead of Guids?

Comment: No, there's no particular reason I'm not using ObjectId values. I was reading through the Driver documentation and thought I try to work through an example. I'll give SetIdMember a try though. 

Would it simple be a matter of changing 'cm.MapIdProperty' to 'cm.SetIdMember'?

The reason why I shyed away from it initially was because the example posted here (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial) showed SetIdMember being used after an AutoMap was being performed.

Comment: When I execute the following code, I get the same error. This code has been taken from [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial):

        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Employee>(cm =>
                                              {
                                                  cm.AutoMap();
                                   cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c=>c.EmployeeId));
                                                        });

Comment: Right, `MapIdProperty` might be what you want in that case.

Comment: Also, check you don't have some data already in the collection with an ObjectId instead of a Guid.  MongoVue is a good way to look at the data quickly, or you can use the console.

Comment: Ok, while examining the collection through MongoVue, I notice that each document does in fact have an ObjectId instead of a Guid. How do I correct this? Am I missing a step in the original code that I posted?

Comment: Solved it! 

Turns out I had some additional documents stored in my collection before I started using BsonClassMap. Their ObjectId was stored in a format native to MongoDB....unfortunately this format couldn't be parsed to a Guid.

To fix the error I ended up wiping out all old entries.